# Best approach to update large JSON files in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

The files I have contain larges JSON arrays where under some sub-objects I would like to update some values. Since the files are large, I was looking into a Streaming API to keep the memory footprint low.

What I'd like to achieve is streaming data in, parsing some specific sub-object, update its values, stringify that sub-object again and efficiently save the updated values back on disk.

I'm not sure how to do that using libraries like Jackson or GSON, because their Streaming API offer a way to do efficient reading (JsonParser or JsonReader), a way to do efficient writing (JsonGenerator or JsonWriter) but not something that let me do both at the same time:

```
try (JsonParser jsonParser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(new File("bigFile.json"))) {
    
    // parsing logic...

    while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
        MyClass obj = mapper.readValue(jsonParser, MyClass.class);
        obj.field1 = "Some new value";
        obj.field2 += 1;
          
        // how to efficiently write `obj` back on disk?
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you could not use JsonParser/JsonReader and JsonGenerator/JsonWriter at the same time.

Comment: @mkrieger1 JsonGenerator/JsonWriter needs an OutputStream and it seems to me that I have to rewrite the whole file, but I need "atomic" updates instead.

Comment: The underlaying operating system does not support inserting and deleting characters in the middle of text files   Therefore you must create a new file to replace your old file when finished.

Comment: You also may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422516/how-to-update-json-value-using-java/64424791#64424791
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868825/split-a-large-json-file-into-smaller-json-files-using-java/61918904#61918904